# Thread interruption

Tags: java, multithreading

So i have a question about the interrupt() method for threads in java. Here is a piece of my code:

```
threads.forEach(Thread::start);
threads.forEach(thread -> {
    try {
        thread.join();
        if (done){
            thread.interrupt();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

Now, as you can see, I begin by starting each thread and joining them. What I want to know is if "thread.interrupt()" does what I think it does. I have created a volatile boolean "done" (which is false by default). And I have another piece of code somewhere, where each thread searches for something in a file.  When that something is found, I set the boolean done to true. And I am hoping that that stops all the other threads that arent finished yet from running.

However, something tells me that this isnt as easy as Im making it be. So I would appreciate it if anyone could tell me if what I did is right - and if not - what exactly this does.

Comment: The threads you start have to handle interruption themself. You didn't provide the implementation so we don't know.

Comment: 'thread.join()'   will wait until the thread returns from its run() method.  After that, there isn't anything to interrupt.

Comment: so if I use iterrupt after threads.start and before threads.join, does tht make any difference? I suppose that defeats the purpouse of join?

Comment: There are dozens of questions here about `Thread.interrupt()` here. Before you do more tests by yourself, I recommend doing [some research](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+thread.interrupt). It's not as simple as it sounds.

Comment: Looking at it from another perspective : maybe the runnable code of your threads should be the one checking the status of `done` and they could terminate themselves, instead of using an external thread (here : the main thread) to control them. Just a thought.

Comment: Also, note: `thread.join()` doesn't do anything else _but_ wait for the thread to terminate. In particular, `thread.join()` doesn't do anything to the thread that would encourage it to terminate.

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to know is if "thread.interrupt()" does what I think it does.

No, it doesn't.

Say you have two threads search for something in a file. When thread2 finds out that thing whatever it is, and sets `done` to `true`, the main thread (the code in your question) may be still waiting for thread1 to terminate, since you invoked `thread.join();` on thread1, and the fact that `threads.forEach` doesn't run in parallel.

The main thread will block on `thread1.join()` until thread1 also finds out the thing, or finishes without anything found, or interrupted by a third thread.

To implement what you intended for, you have to maintain the references of all other threads for every thread you create, and interrupt all other threads when any one thread first finds out the result.

Another way is that do not invoke join for each thread, but busy-checking for the volatile flag `done`, and interrupt each thread on `done == true`.

```
threads.forEach(Thread::start);
while (!done) {
    Thread.sleep(100);
}
threads.forEach(thread -> {
    try {
        thread.interrupt();
    } catch (InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```